# Is there another way to create roles instead of manually taking guild ID to create the role?

Tags: discord.js

I am wondering if anyone can help me to make a role using a command in discord.js v12. I have been able to make the role that I wished by  using this command:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'croles',
    description: 'creates a role',
    execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
        const guildId = ('guild's ID goes in here');
        const roleName = args.join(" ");
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);
        
        if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "mod")){

            guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                name: roleName ,
                color: '#FFFF00',
              },
                reason: 'create a role',
              })
                .catch(console.error);
                message.channel.send( '`'+ roleName + '`' + ' ' +'role have been created.');
        
        } else {

                message.channel.send('u do not have admin roles.');


        }
    }
}
```

Through this code, I'm currently manually taking the server's id and putting into the "guildId" so I can create the role. Currently this method is working but it takes time to add the guild id. I know I can use the "or" function but I'm currently testing this on one server.

Comment: Are you attempting to add this to a certain server or the one you have executed your command in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the guild through the message variable.
`message.guild`, it will return the guild the message was sent in, you can then get the ID of it by appending `.id` to it.

Example:

```js
execute(client, message, args) {
    return message.reply("The Guild ID is: " + message.guild.id);
}
```

Another thing, remove the "Discord" variable from your execute, just re-require it in files that you need it.

Comment: so currently this command gives the bot the guild's ID so it can execute the create role function? I will sure remove the "Discord" var.

Comment: You could just do `message.guild.roles.create` if it's for the same guild. `const guildId = message.guild.id`